# EC2 instance termination deletes EFS volume folder

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment for a WordPress site, configured to use an EFS volume for the uploads folder, mounted and linked on instance creation (followed [this guide](https://parall.ax/blog/view/3212/how-to-run-scalable-wordpress-on-aws-amazon-web-services-tutorial) to set it up). However, when the instance scales up/down, it somehow deletes the uploads folder on the EFS volume, making me restore backups that I've made beforehand ([this -unanswered-](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=795287) appears to be related.)

My efs.config file is as follows:

```
packages:
  yum:
nfs-utils: []
jq: []
files:
  "/tmp/mount-efs.sh" :
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      mkdir -p /mnt/efs
      EFS_NAME=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.EFS_NAME')
      mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 $EFS_NAME:/ /mnt/efs || true
      mkdir -p /mnt/efs/uploads
      chown webapp:webapp /mnt/efs/uploads
commands:
  01_mount:
    command: "/tmp/mount-efs.sh"
container_commands:
  00-mv-wp-content-uploads:
    command: rsync -a /var/app/ondeck/wp-content/uploads/ /mnt/efs/uploads/
  01-rm-wp-content-uploads:
    command: rm -rf /var/app/ondeck/wp-content/uploads
  02-symlink-uploads:
    command: ln -snf /mnt/efs/uploads /var/app/ondeck/wp-content/uploads
  03-chown-uploads:
    command: chown -h webapp:webapp /var/app/ondeck/wp-content/uploads
```

Essentially, what I'm doing is:

Moving whatever files are in the upload folder for the deployment, deleting that folder to replace it with a symlinked version from EFS and changing its ownership to the Apache user. Seems simple enough, but the EFS folder is getting deleted and replaced with whatever content the deployed file has.

Am I doing something wrong under the container commands?

Comment: You say EBS, but your `/mnt/efs` seems to indicate it's EFS. The two are very different - which is it?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I'll edit the question to reflect the correct one.

Comment: Do you understand what `|| true` means, on the end of your EFS mount command?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot If I understand correctly, it's for going ahead even if the mount command fails.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is long-time asked question, and I did run into the exact same issue. Searches got me here with no answers. I figured out the solution.. Here it is for the sake of record :-)

What you need to use is [Platforms Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html), that is how I accomplished the needed setup and solved the issue.

1. In your AWS EB configurations, create an ENV variable: `EFS_NAME` with your EFS name for its value.
2. Inside the root of your project folder, create the folders with command below:

> mkdir -p .platform/hooks/{predeploy,prebuild,postdeploy}

3. Create the file below, with the contents next:

> nano .platform/hooks/predeploy/001-efs

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
yum -y install amazon-efs-utils jq
mkdir -p /mnt/efs
EFS_NAME=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.EFS_NAME')
mount -t efs -o tls $EFS_NAME:/ /mnt/efs || true
mkdir -p /mnt/efs/wp-uploads
chown -R webapp:webapp /mnt/efs/wp-uploads
```

4. Create the file below, with the content next:

> nano .platform/hooks/postdeploy/001-efs

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Make suer, uploads folder is there.. Just in case:
mkdir -p /var/app/current/wp-content/uploads

# Copy files to mounted EFS, maybe from the initial setup, or a migrated one:
rsync -av /var/app/current/wp-content/uploads /mnt/efs/wp-uploads/

# Delete the uploads folder afterward:
rm -rf /var/app/current/wp-content/uploads

# Create a symbolic link to the mounted EFS folder:
ln -snf /mnt/efs/wp-uploads /var/app/current/wp-content/uploads

# Correct ownership of the symbolic link:
chown webapp:webapp -h /var/app/current/wp-content/uploads
```

This is my fully-working code. Still maybe it's not the best but it will get you there prefectly.

Answer (score -1):

The problem, as a commenter above hinted at, is that the mount command fails (in this case, because of incorrect security group configurations) and the "|| true" after it masks the error.

Make sure that the security group for the EC2 instance allows outbound traffic on all ports (or at least, the NFS port with the security group for the EFS set as the destination), and the inbound traffic for the EFS is set to allow the NFS port for TCP. Once you do that, the mount command should succeed, and the instructions above should work.

Comment: His problem is total different.